# Como hacer que un proyecto ya desarrollado tenga url amigables para SEO?

Tags: c#, mvc, seo

Tengo un proyecto **MVC C#** ya desarrollado, ahora quieren que las **url's** sean amigables con SEO, para ello ya me pasaron un excel de como deberían quedar ejemplo:

```
/ProductDetail?productId=10 =>  /nombre-de-producto
```

No se si existe una forma sencilla de hacer esto ¿Alguna idea?

Esta montado en un windows server 2008 R2 y con IIS

Comment: Hola @Gustavo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Qué servidor es? ¿Y cómo se mapea desde un id al nombre? En vez de contestar directamente, sería mejor [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Si estás usando MVC, en algun fichero se estará generando el registro de rutas. Algo parecido a:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Lo que vamos a hacer será crear un nuevo registro de ruta genérica por encima de la ruta Default:

```
        string name = "GenericUrl";
        string url = "{generic}";
        object defaults = new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" };
        object namespaces = new[] { "SampleWebApp.Controllers" };

        var route = new GenericPathRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler()) {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
        };

        if (namespaces != null) {
            route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
        }

        routes.Add(name, route);
```

Esta regla capturará todas las url's y los analizará en una función posterior. Si son "conocidas" podrás redireccionar el destino, y si no lo son, seguirá la ejecución.

Para analizar las url's necesitamos una nueva clase que derive de Route y hay que sobrecargar el método GetRouteData:

```
public class GenericPathRoute : Route {
    public GenericPathRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, routeHandler) { }
    public GenericPathRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, routeHandler) { }
    public GenericPathRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler) { }
    public GenericPathRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler) { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        RouteData data = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        if (data != null) {
            var slug = data.Values["generic"] as string;

            if (slug == "xxx") {
                data.Values["controller"] = "Home";
                data.Values["action"] = "ProductDetails";
                data.Values["productid"] = 1;
                return data;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Dentro del método la variable slug rescata el contenido de la url "genérica" y la puedes trastear como creas conveniente. Ya sea parseando, buscando en base de datos, etc...

El índice "productid" es a modo de ejemplo. En este caso se corresponde al nombre del parámetro de la acción del controlador.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult ProductDetails(int productid) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es un servidor apache sirviendo urls, puedes usar mod_rewrite y el archivo .htaccess para manejar las urls como variables, de tal manera que en el navegador pongas: /producto/89002/lampara-de-noche , y esta se pase como /ProductDetail?productId=89002 , nota que la tercera parte de la url amigable (lampara-de-noche) no se toma en cuenta para hacer la consulta, pero es mostrada y puede ser indexada por los robots de búsqueda.